# python pymssql returns list comma separated, how to change the separator to i.e pipe?

Tags: python, pymssql

I checked pymssql documents for parameters but I couldn't find what I was looking for. Basically when I execute the cursor with my SQL query, I always receive the list as comma separated. I'd like to change comma to another separator since some name fields contains comma. Is there a way to do that?

This is what I have:

```
cnxn = pymssql.connect(
        server=db_server, 
        port=12345, 
        database='DataBase', 
        user=username, 
        password=password)

cursor = cnxn.cursor(as_dict=False)


#sql_statement = "SELECT Name FROM table"
               
cursor.execute(sql_statement)
rows=list(cursor.fetchall())

print(rows)
```

Output:
[('Name,1', '20221110'), ('Name2', '20221115')]

What I need:

[('Name,1'|'20221110'), ('Name2'|'20221115')]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm making an assumption based on your comment about the need for a non-comma separator to avoid conflicts with the commas in your fields that you would be okay with something like this:

```
rows = [('Name,1', '20221110'), ('Name2', '20221115')]
for r in rows:
    print("|".join(r))
```

Output:

```
Name,1|20221110
Name2|20221115
```

`join` creates a single concatenated string from a collection of strings that are separated by the specified string.